# Exit with non-zero if input is empty

Tags: jq, exit-code, exitstatus

I am trying to parse my curl output with JQ and check the exit code, so when my curl output is empty, JQ return 0 exit code.

For example:

```
$ echo "" | jq '.key'
$ echo $?
0
```

How to make this return 1 or some non-zero value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `input` with `-n`/`--null-input` on the command line. This way JQ will fail if its input is empty.

```
$ echo | jq -n 'input.key'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): break
$ echo $?
5
```

```
$ jq -n '{key: 1}' | jq -n 'input.key'
1
$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to specify the return code when the input is empty, you could use `halt_error/1`, like so:

```
$ echo "" | jq -n 'try input.key catch halt_error(9)' 2> /dev/null
$ echo $?
9
```